# Merging multiple Validated into single one

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have written this code

```
def valid1() : Validated[List[String], Boolean] = {...}
def valid2() : Validated[List[String], Boolean] = {...}
def valid3() : Validated[List[String], Boolean] = {...}
def valid4() : Validated[List[String], Boolean] = {...}
val consolidated = valid1 |@| valid2 |@| valid3 |@| valid4
consolidated.map{_ && _ && _ && _} match {
  case Valid(true) => // do something
  case Invalid(errorList) => // do something
}
```

Instead of doing `|@|` on each intermediate validation and doing a `&&` inside the map... can I write it in a simpler way? I guess individually trying to do `|@|` and then `&&` makes the code look a little scary. (sorry I am not a jedi yet)

Comment: Cats recently removed Xor class from the lib, maybe you should try another version or re-examine your dependencies

Comment: yes. I downgraded to 0.7.2 and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sequence` (or `sequenceU`).

```
import cats.data.{NonEmptyList, Validated}
import cats.implicits._
// import cats.syntax.reducible._
// import cats.syntax.traverse._

val valids = NonEmptyList.of(valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4)

val consolidated: Validated[List[String], Boolean] =
  valids.sequenceU.map(_.reduceLeft(_ && _))
```

`Validated[List[String], Boolean]` is sort of a strange type as it can represent two invalid/false cases : `Invalid(messagesList)` and `Valid(false)`. As you are only pattern matching `Valid(true)` (not `Valid(false)`), this can probably also be modelled as `Validated[List[String], Unit]`.

```
// import cats.syntax.foldable._

val consolidated2: Validated[List[String], Unit] =
  valids.traverseU_(_.ensure("was false" :: Nil)(identity))

consolidated2.fold(
  errorList => // do something 
  , _ => // do something
)
```

---

For the compiler error: You probably have another dependency using an older version of Cats. Cats dropped the `Xor` data type in favour of `Either` in [version 0.8.0](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v0.8.0).